# Error:You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter as my PHP framework, and I keep getting this error when I submit my data to my database.

I am already using set in the controller. I am not sure why I have this error:

> You must use the “set” method to update an entry

My model:

```
public function update_reserve($data,$book_id)
{    
    $this->db->where('book_id',$book_id);
    $this->db->update('books',$data);
    return TRUE;
}
```

My controller:

```
public function out()
{  
    $book_id = $this->input->post('book_id');
    if(isset($_POST['btn_reserve'])) {
       $data = array(  
       'pickup' =>$this->input->post('pickup'),
       'return' =>$this->input->post('return'),);
        if(!empty($data)) {
            $this->user_model->update_reserve($book_id,$data);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model, You can use "set" method:

```
public function update_reserve($data,$book_id)
{    
    $this->db->where('book_id',$book_id);
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->update('books');
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Now don't have the issue with set but datetime is not updated to the database .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call your method like this

```
$this->user_model->update_reserve($data,$book_id);
```

to see result